# Impresspages CMS 4.2.6 and Brightr theme

Tags: impresspages

After updating to version 4.2.6 and using the Brightr theme I have a strange behaviour with the form on: http://www.familienpflege-daheim.de/kontakt After sending the filled form there is no reloaded comment-site. The email is sent, but the user doesn't know, what happens.
And I can't use the maps plugin of the theme any longer. With my coordiantes the map-pin is in the atlantic ocean …
Using another theme (for example "air") the form works.
Any ideas? Regards. Uwe

Comment: Contact theme developer for these issues. Could be some small compatibility bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look if you  have following folder Theme/Brightr/override

review all files in there. If you see something related to form. Try to remove. That may help.